# Garbage disposal problem -- do i need to replace?

Tags: garbage-disposal

My garbage disposal ([2008 InSinkErator Evolution Compact](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000G837TW)) started leaking today because the rubber of [this part](https://www.heritageparts.com/Manufacturers/InSinkErator/INSINKERATOR-COUPLER%2C-FLEX/p/ISE75499) that connects to the tail pipe split open. I pulled it off and noticed [this on the inside of the disposal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvkgw.jpg). I know nothing about disposals, but that doesn't look right to me -- so before I go through the effort of trying to fix it, is this the sign of a greater problem and should I be replacing the entire disposal?

This is the first issue I've had with the disposal in the 2+ years I've owned the house -- so will cleaning it up and replacing the part be enough? [More photos of disposal here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmPsy.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... should I be replacing the entire disposal?

You could try removing the *disposer* and cleaning up the **waste elbow outlet**, which looks like it may have been permanently damaged by corrosion. As a note, you can remove the disposer without disturbing the sink flange/basket assembly by tapping the large fastening ring counter-clockwise until it releases.

The waste elbow outlet requires a specific type of gasket particular to that brand of disposer, and the connection is held with a special plate and screw. Confirm that you have these, then reassemble and test to ensure it does not leak. Your only alternative is to replace the entire unit.

Comment: I was able to replace the gasket and plate and it isn't leaking anymore. Do you think the elbow outlet being damaged led to the premature failure of the original gasket? I guess I'm wondering if this just bought me some time, or if they're unrelated problems.

Comment: It's a "chicken/egg" scenario; a failed gasket could cause a slow leak leading to corrosion. Existing corrosion could cause a slow leak at gasket, leading to...